# Custom shortcut to i3lock screen

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, screen-lock, i3

I'm having difficulties with creating a custom keyboard shortcut. I'm trying to lock my screen using `i3lock` with a picture.

From the terminal, the command

```
i3lock -i ~/Pictures/lock.png
```

works like charm.

When I go `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Custom Shortcut` what do I write into the `Command` line?

I've tried:

```
gnome-terminal -e "i3lock -i ~/Pictures/lock.png"
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does using the same command used in the terminal not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to solve it - maybe it's not the most elegant way but it works and it's good enough.

First I wrote a small script:

`#!/bin/sh
i3lock -i ~/Pictures/lock.png`

Saved it (e.g. `.locker`) to the `HOME` address, then I ran `"chmod +x .locker"` so I could execute it and at the `Custom Shortcuts` to the `Command` line I wrote `./.locker`

Choose an arbitrary shortcut for it (mine is `SUPER+L`).

Answer (score 3):

Another way to solve this is in your i3 config (probably at ~/.i3/config) do something like :

`bindsym Control+mod1+l exec i3lock -i ~/Pictures/lock.png`

or

`bindsym Control+mod1+l exec ~/.i3/scripts/locker`

And remove any gnome shortcut that mirrors what you want to use. Obviously, the shortcut can be specified as wanted.